# ElasticSearch: how to use timezone from the doc to query on date range

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
    GET /services/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": [
    "doc.time",
    "doc.timezone"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "doc.time": {
              "gte": "now-7d/d",
              "time_zone": "US/Pacific"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query works.

Each doc has its own time zone which is specified inside Elastic Search document. 
I need to use doc.timezone instead of "US/Pacific".

Is that possible to achieve in Elastic Search?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the docs for the past week in each time zone? Then maybe aggregate on time zone field and then filter?

Comment: I would be nice to show a sample document

Comment: @sramalingam24 I need to convert doc.time to local time inside the query, so 7 days ago start from midnight of local time. Otherwise, 7 days ago start from midnight UTC, which is not the same as start of the day on local time.

Comment: @Val, the doc contains a lot of unrelated staff which I need to extract based on doc.time. The staff is contact info which I need to extract for users that had an event that happened no later than 7 days ago on local time zone (starting from local midnight).

Comment: @allasorokina Wouldn't it be supplied by user/searcher or even the client app can detect location and supply it. Still not sure why you would want the doc.time or how you would use it.

Comment: @AllaSorokina it always helps to see something concrete, as such it is hard to understand your problem and hence hard to solve it.

Comment: @AllaSorokina did you get this to work? I'm facing a similar issue.